# Division with Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, division

```
              <?php
                 $txtfield = $_POST['number1'];
                  $arr = explode(' ',trim($txtfield));
                    $operator = $arr[0];
                          $count=count($arr);

                           $sum = array_sum($arr);
                              echo "Sum of the number:".$sum. "<br>";

                  $prod=1;
                   for ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
                     $prod = $prod * $arr[$i];}

                          echo "Product of the numbers:".$prod."<br>";

                             $diff=$arr[1];
                             for ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
                                   $diff= $diff - $arr[$i+1];
                       }

                             echo "Difference of the numbers:".$diff."<br>";

                                 $div=$arr[1];
                                     foreach ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
                                   $div=$div / $arr[$i];
                          }

                                  echo "Qoutient of the numbers:". $div. "<br>";
                            ?>
```

This line of code doesn't seem to work properly. When I entered `10` & `5` the output is:

```
Sum of the number:15
Product of the numbers:50
Difference of the numbers:5
Qoutient of the numbers:0.2
```

Comment: why does it displays 0.2 instead of 2

Comment: Your code excerpt is too small to understand what is going on properly.

Comment: You entered `5` and `10` where? Into which variables? And where does this code output anything? And don't forget the `/=` operator...

Comment: Show the **reproducible** full code, expected result, actual result,

Comment: <code><?php
$txtfield = $_POST['number1'];
$arr = explode(' ',trim($txtfield));
$operator = $arr[0];
$count=count($arr);

$sum = array_sum($arr);
echo "Sum of the number:".$sum. "<br>";

$prod=1;
for ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
$prod = $prod * $arr[$i];}

echo "Product of the numbers:".$prod."<br>";

$diff=$arr[1];
for ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
$diff= $diff - $arr[$i+1];
}

echo "Difference of the numbers:".$diff."<br>";

$div=$arr[1];
foreach ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
$div=$div / $arr[$i];
}

echo "Qoutient of the numbers:". $div. "<br>";
?></code>

Comment: I think you should be indexing at 0, not at 1. If you enter [10,5] as your array, 10 is never processed, because $arr[1] is 5. $arr[0] is 10. And then the for loop starts at 1 and goes up, so 10 is completely ignored.

Comment: the value $arr[0] is a string

Comment: the input format shud be " / 10 5" so indexing will start at 1 because thats where the first integer is

Comment: Please update the question with the full code, not entered into the comments where it's too hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by `I entered 10 & 5` you mean that `$arr` looks like this:

```
$arr = array(
  1 => 10,
  2 => 5
);
```

...then `0.2` is the expected result of the quotient. This is what your code does:

```
$div = 10;
$div = 10 / 10; // 1
$div = 1 / 5; // 0.2
```

I think that you meant to initialise `$i` at 2. This will give your expected output. But a better approach would be this:

```
$arr = array(
  10,
  5
);

// Make a copy of $arr before this if you need the original data intact
$quotient = array_shift($arr);

foreach ($arr as $val) {
  $quotient /= $val;
}
```

Now the element indexes are irrelevant, only the element order is significant.

**EDIT**

Here is how I would write your newly posted full code:

```
// Split on any number of whitespace characters to avoid bad user input
$arr = preg_split('/\s+/', $_POST['number1']);

// Remove the first element of the array so it doesn't interfere with calculations
$operator = array_shift($arr);

// This is fine
$sum = array_sum($arr);

// Product has a function of it's own
$prod = array_product($arr);

// Difference and quotient can be done in one loop
$diff = $quot = array_shift($arr);
foreach ($arr as $val) {
  $diff -= $val;
  $quot \= $val;
}    

// Echo the results
echo "Sum of the number:".$sum."<br>";
echo "Product of the numbers:".$prod."<br>"; 
echo "Difference of the numbers:".$diff."<br>"; 
echo "Qoutient of the numbers:".$quot."<br>";
```

Comment: $arr = array(
  10,
  5
); using this it would not be a dynamic page

Comment: @EllandJunsayPansensoy That's irelevant. DaveRandom's analysis is correct in that you are dividing 10 by itself when you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

I've reformatted your program and added static values so that it will execute standalone.

```
<?php
$arr = array(10, 5);
$count = count($arr);

$sum = array_sum($arr);
echo 'Sum of the number: '.$sum."<br>\n";

$prod = 1;
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $prod *= $arr[$i];
}
echo 'Product of the numbers: '.$prod."<br>\n";

$diff = $arr[0];
for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $diff -= $arr[$i];
}
echo 'Difference of the numbers: '.$diff."<br>\n";

$div = $arr[0];
for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $div /= $arr[$i];
}
echo 'Quotient of the numbers: '.$div."<br>\n";
?>
```

The output of this program is:

```
Sum of the number: 15
Product of the numbers: 50
Difference of the numbers: 5
Quotient of the numbers: 2
```